# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting While inserting two python lists in Mysql

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I imported MySQLdb, and established a database connection.

I am having two lists like below:

```
var_list = ['INFY','WIPR','SUZY','BEL' .....]
var_list2 = ['infosys', 'wipro', 'suzlon', 'bharat electronics', .....]
```

Which I aim to insert into the database. Therefore I write the following two string:

```
var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(varlist))
var_string2 = ','.join('?' * len(varlist2))
```

Now I am trying to insert the values into a MySQL table which has the following columns: `symbol(varchar)`, and `company(varchar)`.

```
query_string = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s);' %(var_string,var_string2)

cur.execute(query_string, (varlist,varlist2))
```

This however does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question I think you aim to do bulk insert. You can modify your code as follows but **I strongly advice against that**:

```
query_string = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES %s;'%(','.join('(%s,%s)'*len(varlist)))
flatten = tuple(x for xs in zip(varlist,varlist2) for x in xs)
cur.execute(query_string,flatten)
```

Here you will generate a `query_string` that looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s,%s),(%s,%s),(%s,%s),(%s,%s),(%s,%s);
```

And then you fill it in with a tuple `('INFY','infosys','WIPR','wipro',...)`

---

You can better use [`.executemany()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id18):

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s,%s);",zip(var_list,var_list2))
```

This will generate longer queries, but the result is both more elegant and safe.